# Laravel manual login function

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I use manual login function in Laravel 5.5. Stuck in login. and check all(5 relevant ) Stack links and didn't find any clue on it.

> **Achievement  is** once user get registered, automatically sign in that user.

---

Error is

> "Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, string given, called in Server/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php on line 294 ◀"

```
if ($validator->fails()) {

//            $messages = $validator->messages();

            return Redirect::to('register')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();

        } else {

            $email = Input::get('email');
            $user = new user;
            $user->name     = Input::get('name');
            $user->email    = Input::get('email');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

            $user->save();
//            $userMail = $user->find($email);
            $userMail = User::where('email','=',$email)->first();
            Auth::login($userMail->email, TRUE);
```

am i doing anything wrong. Please guide me.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Login function needs user of type `Authenticatable` and you just given `email` which is string thats why you get this error, Either use `Auth::loginUsingId($id);`

```
 $user = User::where('email','=',$email)->first();
 Auth::loginUsingId($user->id, TRUE);
```

Or just

```
Auth::login($user);
```

Comment: how to check authenticated user details ?

Comment: @StackUser :  to get user details use `\Auth::user();`

Comment: you are not checked the password

Comment: Dear @AmiroucheZeggagh this answer is for `Auto Login` where password not requires. Please read about  `Auto login in laravel`

Answer (score 4):

> Instead of this

Auth::login($userMail->email, TRUE);

> Use this

Auth::login($user->id, TRUE);

Answer (score 3):

```
$email = $request->email;
    $password = md5($request->password);

    if ($request->remember_me == 1) {
        $cookie =  Cookie::queue('username', $email, time() + 31536000);
    } else {
        $cookie =  Cookie::queue('username', '', time() - 100);
    }

    $user = DB::table('tbl_adminuser')->where('email_address', $email)->where('password', $password)->first();
    $request->session()->put('userData', $user);
```

=> You can manual login like this in laravel

Comment: You should never use md5 for a password. Instead use the built in password hashing functions: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/hashing

Answer (score 2):

The `Auth::login()` function expects an Authenticable object. If you have not messed with the `User` class, this will be what you need to pass in.

`Auth::login($user, true);`

Reference: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.html#method_login

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Auth::login($userMail, TRUE);` instead of `Auth::login($userMail->email, TRUE);`

For more info check: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.html#method_login

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 7.

**Manual Login**
Use this method for login.

```
public function check_login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    } else {
        return redirect('/login')->with('error', 'Invalid Email address or Password');
    }
}
```

If you are using a different model class other than the default('User'), then -> navigate to config/auth.php and edit this

```
 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
```

to

```
 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Staff::class,
        ],
```

Note: I have replaced **User** with my model class **Staff**.

Finally go to your model class and instead of extending Model, extend User. ie

From

```
class Staff extends Model
{
```

to

```
class Staff extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User
{
```

**That's it.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass/return the `$user` like this

```
if ($validator->fails()) {

//            $messages = $validator->messages();

            return Redirect::to('register')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();

        } else {

            $email = Input::get('email');
            $user = new user;
            $user->name     = Input::get('name');
            $user->email    = Input::get('email');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

            $user->save();
//            

            Auth::login($user);
```

OR

```
Auth::loginUsingId($user->id, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticating-users), you may need to regenerate the session after manually login an user:

```php
        $user = User::firstOrCreate([
            // ...
        ], [
            // ...
        ]);

        Auth::login($user);
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not use the *remember me* feature at all or your *users* table doesn't have the *remember_token*, do not forget to set it to **false** in:

```
Auth::loginUsingId($userId, false);
```

or in:

```
Auth::login($userObject, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers have mentioned where is Auth Class located! We first need to use Auth class

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

And now we have two methods.

First one is using ***user id as an integer***

```
Auth::loginUsingId($user_id, false);
```

Second one is using ***user object (user model)***

```
Auth::login($userObject, false);
```