# How to do Auth in Laravel without passwords?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am really struggling with Laravel auth. I read the manual many times, went to the code, but I still don't understand how the level of intrication of the Auth module.

As far as I understood, the app files that take part of the Auth are:

- Manager: `Auth` (`Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager`)
- Service Provider: `AuthServiceProvider` (`Illuinate\Foundation\Support\ProvidersAuthServiceProvider`)
- Middleware: `Authenticate`
- `Gate`
- Model: `User`
- Controller: `LoginController`

It seems these controllers `LoginController`, `RegisterController`, ... are called by magic, hardcoded deep down in `Illuminate\Routing\Router`. But, I do not want to use or register any `ResetPasswordController`, neither `ForgotPasswordController` simply because I do not hold any passwords on my application.

So in my case I do no store any `email` or `password` in my database. My authentication is done with OAuth2, the only think I do, is collecting an access token that I store on my database.

The question is:

How can I use the builtin Laravel Auth system that I am forced to use anyway because some providers require an access to `app('auth')`?

What then is the best solution in my case?

1. Rewrite the whole Auth Manager and override the `Router` to remove the burred links to the unneeded controllers
2. Tweak the existing Auth system to fulfill my needs

I am quite lost...

Comment: You can check token and Use `Auth::loginUsingId($user->id, TRUE);` I already answered check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46362600/2815635)

Comment: @NikleshRaut Right, but where should I do this? I suppose in a LoginController, but who's calling the `LoginController`?